# MATLAB improving performance of sum operator

Tags: matlab, performance

I have some code with the objective of summing an array when a masking array is true. I need to keep the horizontal dimension intact (ie. can't just do sum(A(mask)) since that will return a scalar). The mask is elements in the matrix close enough to a specific position - I'm calculating this based on the hypotenuse. Is there any way to make this faster, it is part of a larger code but this is the slowest part.

Code:

```
A = rand(1024,8004);        % data set
xidx = 5019; yidx = 325;    % center of circle for mask
mask_radius = 100;          % radius of circle for mask

[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));            % XX and YY matrices
mask = ((XX-xidx).^2 + (YY-yidx).^2) < (mask_radius)^2; % mask is based on hypotenuse

% attempt 1
tic
tmp = A;                    % duplicate data
tmp(~mask) = 0;             % turn it into zeros
data_sum = sum(tmp);        % add
toc

% attempt 2
tic; sum(A.*mask); toc;
```

Comment: `tic`/`toc` is a bad way of timing code. Use `timeit` instead.

Comment: Did you think of extracting a square region from the array that just contains your circle, then doing all computations within the smaller array?

Comment: One other consideration - you can use `sum(A,dim)` to force `sum` to operate in the specified dimension.

Comment: `tic/toc` are not bad ways of timing code.  They are more convenient than `timeit` when you want to include timing points inside a script or function, and since `tic` and `toc` are used by `timeit`, logic would have that it if they are bad then so is `timeit`.

Comment: @PhilGoddard: precision of `tic`/`toc` is poor, repeated runs typically show very different numbers if the time is very short. You also run the risk of including the cost of parsing and compiling the code, rather than just the execution time (this happens only the first time you run the code after a `clear all`). And if you copy-paste the code containing these into the command line, you are not using the JIT at all, and thus timing something different than what you would time within a function. `timeit` takes care of all these issues for you. (Cont.)

Comment: Use `tic`/`toc` only for sections of code that take a second or more to run, and only within an M-file, and make sure to run that file twice.

Comment: @ChrisLuengo, I agree with most of your points, but they just reinforce my original critisism of your original blanket comment that `tic` and `toc` are bad ways of timing code.  It's not `tic` and `toc` that are bad, it's if they aren't used correctly that is bad.  But that goes for any functionality.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a for loop, which according to Matlab lore is a big no-no, but is ~40% faster.

```
tic
[~,b] = find(mask);
v = min(b):max(b);

for ii = 1:length(v)
    s(ii) = sum(A(mask(:,v(ii)), v(ii)));
end
toc

clf
plot(data_sum(data_sum~=0),'LineWidth',2); hold on
plot(s,'o');
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 0.032778 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012450 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.006974 seconds.
```

[image: Code graphical output]

Comment: For loops being slower is *sooooo 2014*. Jokes aside, indeed, for loops are not anymore a slow operation always, particularly for simple operations, thanks to a very improved JIT compiler.

Comment: In some cases, `for` loops can actually out-perform vectorised operations these days - especially if you have a sequence of relatively simple arithmetic operations.

Comment: Also: bug! `s(ii)=...` should be `s(v(ii))` to get the same output as OP.

Comment: Well, this isn't necessarily a bug. Why would you want to keep all the zeros in the OP's output vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a lot of time by not evaluating the mask in regions of the input matrix you know are outside the circle (i.e. if one of the axes are more than `mask_radius` away from the selected point, and by not summing in those areas.

You can do this very simply by cropping the matrix to a square of half-size `mask_radius`. This would be the code:

```matlab
[height,width] = size(A);
left = max(xidx - mask_radius, 1);
right = min(xidx + mask_radius, width);
top = max(yidx - mask_radius, 1);
bottom = min(yidx + mask_radius, height);
A = A(top:bottom, left:right);
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));            
mask = ((XX-(xidx-left+1)).^2 + (YY-(yidx-top+1)).^2) < (mask_radius)^2;
A(~mask) = 0;
out = sum(A);
out = [zeros(1,left-1),out]; % pad result to the left
out(width) = 0;              % pad result to the right
```

We can further speed this up a bit by not using `meshgrid`, but relying on implicit singleton expansion:

```matlab
XX = 1:size(A,2); YY = (1:size(A,1)).';
mask = ((XX-(xidx-left+1)).^2 + (YY-(yidx-top+1)).^2) < mask_radius^2;
```

I have included the time needed to create the mask in the timing below. If you were to time only the summing you'd still have a significant time saving, but I think creating the mask is part of your task.

Note I'm using `timeit` to time the code. Anything below a second in execution time should be timed using `timeit` as it is a lot more precise than `tic`/`toc`.

```matlab
A = rand(1024,8004);        % data set
xidx = 5019; yidx = 325;    % center of circle for mask
mask_radius = 100;          % radius of circle for mask

res1 = method1(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius);
res2 = method2(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius);
res3 = method3(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius);
res4 = method4(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius);
assert(isequal(res1,res2))
assert(isequal(res1,res3))
assert(isequal(res1,res4))

timeit(@()method1(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius))
timeit(@()method2(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius))
timeit(@()method3(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius))
timeit(@()method4(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius))

% OP's method
function out = method1(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius)
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));            % XX and YY matrices
mask = ((XX-xidx).^2 + (YY-yidx).^2) < (mask_radius)^2; % mask is based on hypotenuse
A(~mask) = 0;    % turn it into zeros
out = sum(A);    % add
end

% liorr's method, with preallocation and correct output
function out = method2(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius)
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));
mask = ((XX-xidx).^2 + (YY-yidx).^2) < (mask_radius)^2;
[~,b] = find(mask);
v = min(b):max(b);
out = zeros(1,size(A,2)); % PREALLOCATE!!!
for ii = 1:length(v)
    out(v(ii)) = sum(A(mask(:,v(ii)), v(ii))); % FIXED BUG!!!
end
end

% My method
function out = method3(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius)
[height,width] = size(A);
left = max(xidx - mask_radius, 1);
right = min(xidx + mask_radius, width);
top = max(yidx - mask_radius, 1);
bottom = min(yidx + mask_radius, height);
A = A(top:bottom, left:right);
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));            
mask = ((XX-(xidx-left+1)).^2 + (YY-(yidx-top+1)).^2) < mask_radius^2;
A(~mask) = 0;
out = sum(A);
out = [zeros(1,left-1),out]; % pad to the left
out(width) = 0;              % pad to the right
end

% My method without MESHGRID
function out = method4(A,xidx,yidx,mask_radius)
[height,width] = size(A);
left = max(xidx - mask_radius, 1);
right = min(xidx + mask_radius, width);
top = max(yidx - mask_radius, 1);
bottom = min(yidx + mask_radius, height);
A = A(top:bottom, left:right);
XX = 1:size(A,2); YY = (1:size(A,1)).';
mask = ((XX-(xidx-left+1)).^2 + (YY-(yidx-top+1)).^2) < mask_radius^2;
A(~mask) = 0;
out = sum(A);
out = [zeros(1,left-1),out]; % pad to the left
out(width) = 0;              % pad to the right
end
```

Output on my system (MATLAB R2017a on MacOS):

```
ans =
    0.0733

ans =
    0.0276

ans =
   5.8832e-04

ans =
   2.4890e-04
```